# How to put the results of a query into a variable?

Tags: postgresql, join, plpgsql

I have written a Postgres anonymous block. In which I have written join query on multiple tables like:

```
select a.portal.*, a.p_fb_config.*, a.p_gplus_config  
from a.portal 
   left outer join a.p_fb_config on a.portal.pid = a.p_fb_config.pid 
   left outer join a.p_gplus_config on a.portal.pid = a.p_gplus_config.pid;
```

Now I want to catch this value in variable. So how should I declare that variable?

I need something like:

```
         portal_row a.portal%ROWTYPE;//for 3 tables
```

Comment: You mean as in `OUTER JOIN`(ing) tables `b` `c` `d` to table `a`?

Comment: What do you want for the outcome - example?

Comment: Yes, please give us some data of tables ( name of collumns ) .

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: You have changed your question completely...  However, a  `record` could take all the values you select in the query.

Comment: thanks dezso!!I will try.I got solution to previous question that is why I edited it.

Comment: Variables are not available in plain SQL. I assume this is about plpgsql code once more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed you were using a pl/pgsql block (probably a function).

For the generic case, you can use `record`, it can basically take a row of any structure, often used like

```
DECLARE
    i record;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN SELECT this, that, something, else FROM some_table
    LOOP
        ...
    END LOOP;
```

There is also a possibility of defining a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_portal_data_with_config AS
select a.portal.*, a.p_fb_config.*, a.p_gplus_config  
-- note that this does not work straight away, there will be a column naming collision, 
-- so you'll have to add column aliases (which then makes using * impossible)
from a.portal 
   left outer join a.p_fb_config on portal.pid = p_fb_config.pid 
   left outer join a.p_gplus_config on portal.pid = p_gplus_config.pid;
```

Having this, you can then

```
DECLARE
    i v_portal_data_with_config%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM v_portal_data_with_config WHERE ... ;
```

Sometimes, when having the view makes sense anyway (the query appears in multiple functions, for example), this may me a more convenient way.  However, you introduce an additional dependency which makes harder to change the logic.